# How do I design threading for this program in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I'm creating a program that will do a user-predefined number of tasks, say, 100.

Each task will go out to a server, fetch a response, make a call to another server, then use the response to make yet another call to the previous server.

I want the application to be multithreaded, so when the user presses a button it will launch, say, 10 threads and they will get going.

Once a task is complete, the thread which completed the task will grab another one from the list until there are none left in which case the threads will terminate and something will happen to alert the user the tasks were completed.

Previously when I attempted something similar I ended up with a cop-out where I basically launched 10 threads every N seconds or so and prayed the previous ones were over by then.

My question is, how do I make a number of threads, store them somehow and add tasks to them as they get completed?
I was advised I could add thread references to a list and then check which threads where asleep and force them to do something but I'm not really sure how to do that, though mostly I'm not sure of the overall proper way to approach this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is biased to the notion that starting a lot of threads will make it work better.  Which is very unlikely, using threads only works well when you have a machine with a lot of cores.  It is *very* unlikely to work when you talk to a server.  The overhead is the talking, trying to squeeze the talk into, say, a TCP channel.  Only one of those.  Or that the server is actually capable of scaling properly with multiple pending requests.  This ultimately goes to a "code you didn't write" problem.  Talk to the server dude.  And no, don't expect him to be happy about it.

Comment: @HansPassant - the OP does not make it clear whether each task uses the same pair of servers - if not, then the issue of multiple connections per server may not arise. If an anynchronous solution is not available or not preferred, starting a lot of threads is extremely likely to make it work better, even with only one core, especially if the communication profile is continual connect/disconnect, (blocking DNS lookup, blocking three-way-handshake-connect, some data transfer, blocking 4-way-handshake-disconnect).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure you really understand threading in .net. I found this is be a very good resource [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

Also, new to the table, is Data Parallelism in .net 4. You can read more about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx)

The data parallelism will make your situation easy (Parallel.ForEach), but I truly suggest you hit the books and learn the basics. But, if ignorance is bliss, then MS and Data Parallelism is for you.

If you don't have access to .net 4 and therefore Data Parallelism, then I you'll need a queue of tasks ([Queue(Of T) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)), some lock for your threads to access it securely ([Locking](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking)), background threads ([ThreadPool Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)), and some form of signalling ([Signaling with Wait and Pulse](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Signaling_with_Wait_and_Pulse)).

Bonus. To limit/control threads working at a given time, you may also want to check out [Semaphore](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Semaphore).

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 it should do.  Queueing work is much easier than trying to manage threads - best if they are just created at startup an hang off a blocking queue.  In the case of multiple DNS lookups and multiple TCP connections, a considerable amount of blocking is to be expected - make the pool large, or better, real-time configurable.

Comment: Mate, semaphore is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're asking for is the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx). Essentially, is helps to run tasks concurrently, without having to manage threads yourself. Although, you still have to understand the basics of multithreaded code so you can structure your program in way that supports running tasks in parallel.